# Why is DbGeometry.Distance returning the wrong value in my simple test?

Tags: c#

In a simple test, I run:

```
DbGeometry.PointFromText("POINT ( -70.490367454924666 41.617229044487424)", 4326)
.Distance(DbGeometry.PointFromText("POINT (-78.5498733520508 35.8455619812012)", 4326));
```

The returned value is: 9.9130104405893711

My understanding is that the returned value is in meters, but that's not even close to right.  Those points are many many kilometers apart.  What am I missing?

Comment: what is supposed to be right?

Comment: The actual answer is: 948.2032587590463 km

Comment: One is in North Carolina, and the other is in Boston, MA.

Comment: it looks like arbirrary unit-less points to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing a bit of rounding...

```
-70.5 - -78.5 == 8
42 - 36 == 6
sqrt(8*8 + 6*6) == 10
```

looks close to right to me

Comment: Thanks for that, I can at least now see that the returned value is in decimal degrees, not meters as a few sites described it.  1.0 degree = 111km, so that number is correct.